# Creating an Array based on column heading value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am ultimately trying to create an array of column values based on a column heading on a Google Sheet. I have created an array of the column headings and need to get the column index that one of the values on another sheet holds. There is a drop down on sheet 1 based off of the column headings on sheet2.

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var crew = ss.getRange("E2").getValue()
    var col = ss.getSheetByName("Crews").getLastColumn()
    var cols = ss.getSheetByName("Crews").getRange(1,1,1,col).getValues()
```

The array created for the column headings looks like  [[17110, 12345]] I have tried using indexOf, but it always returns -1

Comment: This statement is not clear: " I have created an array oc the column headings and need to get the column index that one of the values on another sheet holds". Also can you post your indexOf code? indexOf works on a 1D array (ex `[17110, 12345]`), but you have a 2D array ( `[[17110, 12345]]`)

Comment: Edited above. How does one get the column index out of a 2D array then? Cols[0].indexOf(searchvalue). The crew variable holds the value I want to serch for and return the column index

Comment: Yes, `Cols[0].indexOf(searchvalue)` will do the trick, since you only have a single row. Just remember to add 1 to the index to get the actual column number.

Comment: How would I use that variable crew as the serchvalue? I have tried it as [crew] and hard coding the value [17110] and still get -1

Comment: Got it!! Just had to experiment a bit. TY